# What would a script to replace \ with / in many files look like?

Tags: c, windows, posix, include-path

Yes, this is a really lazy question but I figure this is problem that people have often enough that someone here would have something already written to share.

I have a ton of C files with `#include` statements using Windows relative paths. I'm working on compiling the code on other operating systems (immediately, on my OS X development machine) and need to replace all the backslashes with forward slashes in these include statements. So, from something like `#include "libs\helper.h"` to `#include "libs/helper.h"`.

Comment: Looks like a job for a 5-character regex. Assuming you don't use backslashes elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have bash/awk/sed in OS X

```
for cfile in *.c
do
  awk '/#include/{gsub(/\\/,"/")}1' cfile >temp
  mv temp cfile
done
```

or

```
 sed -i.bak '/#include/s/\\/\//g' *.c
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed  '/^[ ]*#[ ]*include/ s:\\:/:g'
```

This should be pretty robust as it should catch any legal format of `#include` but not anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Sed is the way forward so do it on your mac.

`sed '/^#include/s/\\/\//g'`